# Can Apache Pig load data from STDIN instead of a file?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I want to use Apache pig to transform/join data in two files, but I want to implement it step by step, which means, test it from real data, but with a small size(10 lines for example), is it possible to use pig that read from STDIN and output to STDOUT?

Answer (score 2):

Basically Hadoop supports Streaming in [various ways](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/streaming.html), but Pig originally lacked support for loading data through streaming. However there are some solutions.

You can check out [HStreaming](http://hstreaming.com/docs/getting-started/pigscript/):

```
A = LOAD 'http://myurl.com:1234/index.html' USING HStream('\n') AS (f1, f2);
```

Comment: Ok, I will admit that is kind of cool. Never heard of HStreaming. I've always looked at Kafka, Flume, or others to do real-time processing. While have to read more into this.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. The data needs to be out in the cluster on data nodes before any MR job can even run over the data.

However if you are using a small sample of data and are just wanting to do something simple you could use Pig in local mode and just write stdin to a local file and run it through your script.

But the bigger question becomes why are you wanting to use MR/Pig on a stream of data? It was and is not intended for that type of use.

Comment: to answer your question on why he would need to do that, here's anscenario: I have these big log files that I need to analyze using pig; each entry in the log file is a multiline entry which I need to pass through sed to have it made into one line. I wish to pipe each of these lines from sed to pig (that would be two lines from the log file read by sed and made into one line which I would then pipe to pig. Why would you go about that?

Comment: Why not just write a custom load UDF. It would be a much better way and would scale with your Hadoop cluster. If that is not still an option you make check out a different tech like Storm (From Twitter) or maybe even Kafka (From Linkedin). These would seem to be a better option to do a streaming Sed/Awk like task that will scale.